# load a graph with chart.js and react

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am trying to create a graph and I am explicitly trying to do with both React and Chart.js
The idea is pretty simple, you fetch data, then you turn those into a graph.
I have gotten to the point where I made working fetch function and made a ref to acces my "canvas" element to put the graph in.
But when I try to put some random chart example(not yet my actual code), I get nothing. 
My work in progress can be found [here](https://codepen.io/koffiekan/pen/NWNZYNG?editors=1111)
I have been working on this for several hours now and more specifically, I would like to know how and where I do what to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your React component is named 'Chart` and you import chart.js as 'Chart'. Change the name of your React component.